# Establishing rest endpoints on a secure express server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create a node express app that can server some JSON services over https.
Here's my code snippet:

```html
                var https = require("https");
                var secureServer = https.createServer(httpsOptions, expressApp);
                secureServer.listen(port, function () {
                  console.log("Example app listening on port " + port);
                });
                establishQAToolEndpoints(expressApp);
```

In the establishQAToolEndpoints function, I attach some rest services to the app like this:

```html
function establishQAToolEndpoints(server)
{
    console.log("Setting up rest services");
    server.get("/api/userActions/partners", (request, response) => {
    ......
    server.get("/api/userActions/allUsers", (request, response) => {
```

However, when I run the server and go to https://localhost:3000/api/userActions/allUsers
I get a not found error.  How do I attach these endpoints to the secureServer?

Answer (score 0):

See , you can not open localhost with protocol  **https**
For that you need additional package and some settings

Prefer [ngRok](https://ngrok.com/docs/2) documentation